# ngResource: Making a POST request to a specific item

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-resource, ngresource

I have the following basic API for a forum:

- `POST /topics` (create new topic)
- `GET /topics` (get all topics)
- `GET /topics/1` (get topic with ID "1")

And I want to add the following:

- `POST /topics/1` (add reply to topic with ID "1")

I have tried the following code (relevant excerpt), but it hasn't worked:

```
.controller('TopicReplyController', function ($scope, $routeParams, Topics) {
    'use strict';

    var topicId = Number($routeParams.topicId);

    Topics.get({topicId: topicId}, function (res) {
        $scope.topic = res;
    });

    $scope.postReply = function () {
        var newPost = new Topics({
            topicId: topicId
        });

        newPost.text = $scope.postText;
        newPost.$save(); // Should post to /topics/whatever, not just /topics
    };
})
.factory('Topics', function ($resource) {
    'use strict';

    return $resource('/topics/:topicId', {topicId: '@id'});
});
```

It just makes a request to `/topics`, which doesn't work.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Do you want to update /topics/1 or create a new 'topic' with ID 1?

Comment: I want to add a new post to the topic with ID 1, which requires sending a POST request to /topics/1. It's unusual, but it's still RESTful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [$resource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#usage_parameters):

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value of that parameter is extracted from the data object (useful for non-GET operations).`

You are specifying that the `topicId` will be the `id` of the object you are using.

```
$resource('/topics/:topicId', {topicId: '@id'});
                            // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                            // Here is where you are mapping it
```

You want to pass `id: topicId` so that it will map `id` to `topicId` in the URL.

```
var newPost = new Topics({
    id: topicId
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It isn't how I ended up doing it in the end—instead, I specified it in an object as an argument in `.$save()`, but I'll test whether yours works later and mark it as the solution if it works as well.